# Fetch not working after switch from class to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm converting some class components to functional.

Console.log(data) returns the expected output but then once i try to set it using useState and check the value, it returns an empty array.

On the class component its working by using the state.

**Functional Component ( Not Working )**

```
    const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
    const [watingForResult, setWaitingForResult] = useState(false)
    const [submission, setSubmission] = useState([]);
    const [scoringResults, setScoringResults] = useState([]);
+
    function submitSubmission() {
        setSubmitting(true);
        setResult([]);
        setError('');

        let data = {
            code: btoa(code),
            language: { name: language.name },
            users: { username: parseLocalJwt().username },
            problem: { name: textToLowerCaseNoSpaces(problem.name) }
        }

        fetch(URL + '/submission', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: new Headers({
                ...getAuthorization(),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            setSubmitting(true);
            setWaitingForResult(true);
            setSubmission(data);

            console.log('submitSubmission' + JSON.stringify(data));

            window.secondsWaiting = new Date().getTime();
            window.resultsListener = setInterval(fetchForResults(data.id), 1000);
        });

    }
 
    ...

     function fetchForResults() {
        console.log('data on fetchForResults' + submission.id) 
     }

    ...

     <button
       type="button"
       onClick={submitSubmission}>
       Submit!
     </button>
```

console.log screenshot

[image]

**Class component ( Working )**

```
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            problem: [],
            sentSubmission: {
                submitting: false,
                waitingForResults: false,
                submission: [],
                scoringResults: []
            },
            results: {
                loaded: false,
                result: [],
                error: ''
            },
            language: { mode: 'java', name: 'Java' },
            code: ``
        }


    submitSubmission() {
        this.setState({ sentSubmission: { submitting: true }, results: { result: [], error: '' } })
        let data = {
            code: btoa(this.state.code),
            language: { name: this.state.language.name },
            users: { username: parseLocalJwt().username },
            problem: { name: textToLowerCaseNoSpaces(this.state.problem.name) }
        }


        fetch(URL + '/submission', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: new Headers({
                ...getAuthorization(),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({ sentSubmission: { submitting: true, waitingForResults: true, submission: data } })
            window.secondsWaiting = new Date().getTime();
            window.resultsListener = setInterval(this.fetchForResults, 1000);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Please add where are you calling your `submitSubmission`. Furthermore, I also need the code of `fetchForResults`

Comment: Added! ```fetchForResults``` will do another fetch based on the State which is coming as undefined. ```submitSubmission``` is just a regular button! Also added screenshot of the console logs!

Answer (score 2):

Some portion of the code is missing but, since you switched from a class component's state to a functional component state, I guess the issue is related to how you are using your state.

In functional components, when you set your state, you are **changing the whole object in your state**. So, when in your code you do `setSentSubmission({ submitting: true });`, your state becomes:

```
previousState = { 
       submitting: false,
       waitingForResults: false,
       submission: [],
       scoringResults: []
}
nextState = {
    submitting: true
    //you lost watingForResults, submissions and scoring results
}
```

When using `useState` it is always suggested to decompose your object in different states:

```
const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
const [watingForResult, setWaitingForResult] = useState(false)
//and so on...

//And then update them singularly:
//This...
setSentSubmission({ submitting: true }); 
//... become this
setSubmitting(true);
```

Finally, side note on lists. If you need to add a single element to a list in your state you can do:

```
setListState(currentList => [...currentList, newElement])
```

If this approach doesn't fit your use case and you need a more complex state management system I suggest you to look at `useReducer` ([link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)).

**Update**

To print the content of your fetch you have either 2 choices.

1. Print directly the content retrieved in your fetch function

```
fetch('http://myendpoint.com/mydata.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

2. If you need to do some processing to your data and you want to print what is the content of your updated state you can just use a `useEffect` hook. For instance, if you want to print the content of your `scoringResult` state you just write:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(scoringResult)
},[scoringResult])
```

This hook will be triggered every time `scoringResult` is updated (plus once when the component was mounted in the beginning)

Comment: I've made the changes as suggested still not working! But it makes a lot sense splitting all the state into a single useState becomes way easier to work with!

Comment: @zemmsoares I've update the answer with 2 ways to print your data

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is this:

```
setSentSubmission(...)
console.log(data);
console.log(sentSubmission.submission)
```

You can not set state and then to expect immediately to access that new state, new state can be accessed after component rerenders(in next iteration), all this is because you are reading `sentSubmission.submission` from closure which will be recreated only when component rerenders. So everything works fine with you code, you are just doing logging in a wrong place, move that log outside of the `submitSubmission` and you will see that state is updated successfully and that log will be printed after component rerenders(state updates).

Comment: This seems to be the problem!  ```useEffect(() => {console.log(submission);}, [submission])``` prints the desired output, but how can i acess it on ```fetchForResults```?

Comment: You should rewrite fetchForResult so it accept one argument and inside .then() call function with data from fetch response, instead of data from state.

Answer (score 0):

When function submit() call, you set new value for **sentSubmission**.
Try this instead:
setSentSubmission((prevState) => (…prevState, { submitting: true }));